# Play 2 template how to access an entity member of type list

Tags: java, frameworks, playframework-2.0

My entities are: UserShoppingList, Product and Category as follows:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;

import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.Validation;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;

/**
 * Entity managed by Ebean
 */


@Entity
public class UserShoppingList extends Model{

      @Id
      public Long id;

      @Required
      public String listName;

      @ManyToOne
      public User user;

      @ManyToMany
      public List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

      //getters and setters

//(I have included them, not shown here)

package models;

import java.util.*;

import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Product entity managed by Ebean
 */

@Entity
public class Product extends Model{
     @Id
     public Long Id;

     @ManyToOne
     public Category category;

     @Required
     public String brandName;

     @Required
     public String productName;


    // -- Queries

     public static Model.Finder<Long,Product> find = new Model.Finder(Long.class, Product.class);

package models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.*;
import play.db.jpa.*;

/**
 * Category entity managed by JPA
 */
@Entity 

public class Category {
     @Id
     public Long id;


     @Constraints.Required
     public String categoryName;

     // --getters and setters
```

My template:

```
@(shoppinglist: List[models.Product], categorylist: List[Category], 
userShoppingListsForm: Form[models.UserShoppingList])

@import helper._


@main("Shopping list products") {

    var productlist = shoppinglist.getProducts()

    <h1>Shopping List</h1>


    @for(c <- categorylist){

    <ul>

            <li class = "categoryrow">@categorylist.getCategoryName()</li>



            @for(p <- productlist) {


            <ul>
                <li class="productcolumn">  
                    @p.getBrandName()
                </li>

                <li class="productcolumn">  
                    @p.getProductName()
                </li>               

                <li class="command">
                    id = @p.getId()!
                    @form(routes.ShoppingLists.deleteProduct(id)) {
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                    }
                </li>

            </ul>

            }



        </ul>

        }



        <h2>Add a product to list</h2>

        @form(routes.ShoppingLists.newUserShoppingList()) {

            @inputText(userShoppingListsForm("listName")) 

            <input type="submit" value="Create">

        }



}
```

I am getting following error:

> value `getCategoryName` is not a member of `java.util.List[models.Category]`

Can somebody suggest me better way to create template for java based Play 2 Framework to access entity membefrs which are lists themselves (example: products in "UserShoppingList" please?

Any help hugely appreciated. Thanks a million

Comment: To ask a follow-up question, you should add it as a comment below the answer and edit it into your original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a getter for the list element, but you're trying to use it on the whole `List`

Probably this is right solution:

```
<li class = "categoryrow">@c.getCategoryName()</li>
```

Comment: Many thanks. My main issue is accessing entity members which are of type list from template. see code    @for(p <- productlist) { giving error: not found: value productlist. I had defined it as " var productlist = shoppinglist.getProducts()" in template.